# jquery show and hide div over

Tags: javascript, jquery

I try show cover over image , for this i use this little code :

```
<script>
function carrousel_show_cover(id)
{   
$(".c_cover_"+id).show(2000);   
}

function carrousel_hide_cover(id)
{   
$(".c_cover_"+id).hide(10);
}
</script>


 <div id="content_pic" onmouseover="carrousel_show_cover('1')" onmouseout="carrousel_hide_cover('1')">
<div class="c_cover_1" style="display:none;"></div>
<img src="test_image.jpg">
</div>
```

The problem here it´s , yes show cover over the image but the same time hide the cover and all time show , hide , hide and show .....  , i want when put cursor over , show the cover and when i put mouse out hide the cover , but no get this , some idea ?

Thank´s

Comment: Sounds like the mouseout needs to be on the cover.

Answer (score 1):

You could also separate your javascript from your HTML easily by doing something like this

```
<div class="card-container">
    <img src="test_image.jpg" class="card"/>
    <div class="card cover"></div>
</div>
```

and you control the hover action with

```
$('.card-container').hover(function() {
    $('.card.cover', this).hide()
}, function() {
    $('.card.cover', this).show()
});
```

I used different class names than you did but the concept is there.

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/NThK2/

Answer (score 0):

The `.c_cover_1` div is empty. Nothing can be displayed.

```
<div id="content_pic" onmouseover="carrousel_show_cover('1')" onmouseout="carrousel_hide_cover('1')">
    <div class="c_cover_1" style="display:none;">
        <img src="cover_image.jpg" />
    </div>
    <img src="test_image.jpg">
</div>
```